# how can I work with wrapped data using moshi, retrofit and java?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, moshi

I'm working with an API where all data are wrapped in a custom object (see below), so I cannot use moshi to convert the retrofit body direct to my models. What is the best way to work with moshi in this case?

```
#COLLECTIONS ENDPOINT

{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 28122,
            "name": "Abandonei",
            "counts": {
                "books": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 21091,
            "name": "Lendo",
            "counts": {
                "books": 6
            }
        },
    ],
    "errors": [],
    "pagination": {
        "after": 2,
        "hasNextPage": true
    }
}
```

The same json structure is used in all api endpoints, the default fields are:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [],
    "errors": [],
    "pagination": {
        "after": 1,
        "hasNextPage": true
    }
}
```

My Collection model:

```
public class BookCollection {
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Book> books;

    public BookCollection(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What code do you have now for your model? Your moshi adapter should be able to handle this data without any issues.

Comment: @RayHunter I added the model I use in this request and an example of the json returned by the api on all endpoints

Comment: You json needs to match your model. So instead of BookCollection you could create a new one that has all the fields in the json data coming back.

Comment: But in that way I'll need to create a parent class to all my models. I think that it's not the best practice to work. In Gson I can create a custom adapter that will be used on the parser proccess to get only the data inside json data attribute and after that use may models to return the parsed data.  I know that it's possible in Moshi too, but I don't know how can I do that.

Comment: That is correct, the api is forcing you to wrap it with a custom parent class. I am not a huge fan of this type of json response. The status and errors should be handled at the http level and not in the response payload. For moshi, you can create an adapter that could handle the parent and the process the data and give you back the java/kotlin object back. Gson can do it with a custom deserializer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid create a parent class to each model, I have implemented a way to use a class that receive a generic type.

To put this to work I've changed the Moshi class to Gson.

My model:

```
public class BookCollection {
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Book> books;

    public BookCollection(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The wrapper class used to unwrap the json data:

```
public class ApiWrapper<T> {
    public final int status;
    public final T data;
    public final List<ApiError> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    public ApiWrapper(int status, T data, List<ApiError> errors) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
        this.errors.addAll(errors);
    }

}
```

The Errors class, referenced in the class above:

```
public class ApiError {
    public int code;
    public String message;
    public String error;
}
```

Usage:

```
public interface NetAPI {
    @GET("me/collections")
    Call<ResponseBody> getCollections(@Header("Authorization") String auth);
}

public class CollectionViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<List<Collection>> collections = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> loading = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> collectionError = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private Call<ResponseBody> call;
    
    private void fetchCollections() {
        loading.setValue(true);
        call = Api.getInstance().getCollections(TOKEN);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    collectionError.setValue(false);
                    
                    //THE SECRET
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    ApiWrapper<List<Collection>> apiResponse = null;
                    apiResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body().string(), new TypeToken<ApiWrapper<List<Collection>>>(){}.getType());

                    collections.setValue(apiResponse.data);

                    loading.setValue(false);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error loading data", t);
                collectionError.setValue(true);
                loading.setValue(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

At this way I can reuse my ApiWrapper class to any model (Books, Users, Login, etc).

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to setup gson/moshi to use your classes that you have created for the json to object mapping. Here is an example of what those java classes would look like. You can use data classes in kotlin as well. For moshi, you will have to create the adapter to help with the json to object mapping.

```
publci class CollectionResponse {

    public int status;
    public List<BookCollection> data;
    public List<Error> errors;
    public Pagination pagination;
}

public class Pagination {
    public int after;
    public boolean hasNextPage;
}

public class BookCollection {
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public Count counts;
    
}

public Count {
    public int books;
}

public class Error {
    
}
```

Comment: But in that way I'll need to create a parent class to all my models. I think that it's not the best practice to work. I'd like to create a custom adapter to be used on the parser proccess to get only the data inside json data attribute and after that use may models to return the parsed data.

Comment: Having a parent class is oop, so that is fine to have. You just need to make sure that the data object can be handled for the different data types you might have. A deserializer (gson) or you moshi adapter can help with that too.

Comment: Thanks man, but I think that create a lot of classes that repeat the same piece of code isn't the best OOP approach. My idea is create a unique unwrap class that I can reuse throughout the project. See my answer below.